# What is the best way to measure bandwidth/connection quality in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

We are using Twilio video in iOS and Android (through a react-native extension).  We would like to warn users about lousy connections if they are making a call.  Is there something buried in Twilio's SDKs to do this?  Or do people have suggestions for a great library to measure connection quality? (for instance: https://www.npmjs.com/package/network-js)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In WebRTC implementations there is normally a way to get the connection statistics. In iOS using Twilio Video, you need to call the [`getStatsWithBlock` method on the room](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.5/docs/Classes/TVIRoom.html#//api/name/getStatsWithBlock:). In Android you want the [`getStats` method on the room](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/video/releases/1.3.2/docs/com/twilio/video/Room.html#getStats-com.twilio.video.StatsListener-). I don't know how you've made your react-native wrapper, but those are the bits you are looking for.

Once you've got the stats, you can start looking for [the track stats, which will give you information about the frames per second, frames received, frames dropped, etc](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#mststats-dict*). This means you can judge the quality of the call not on the network, but on the data being sent and received.

Sorry I can't be more specific, hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: Yes, this is what we are experimenting with now.  We have started with bandwidth.  What isn't clear is if participant A's connection is poor, but B's is good, how you can tell the difference.  It seems like both of them will have lower bandwidth since B can't send much to A?

Comment: I don't think the issue is one of bandwidth in this case, it could be latency, packet loss or any sort of other network problem. Which is why measuring the actual quality of the call itself is better. On the other hand, if one participant out of two has a poor connection, then you are right, both sides of the call will be affected by it anyway so you need to work to improve the connection or lessen the impact of the call for both participants.

Comment: I'm coming here from google search, I'm trying to measure network speed it ends using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-network-bandwith-speed